# What's the white thing which corrects text called in English?

Tags: terminology, image-identification

What's the thing *which correct text by white fluid applying* called in English?

The dictionary in my native language says it's called: **correcting fluid**, or **white-out**, but in fact my classmates call it **'corrector'** (as it's called in the eastern Europe countries: Russian, Ukraine, Belarus, Polish, and many other languages such as: Spanish, Bulgarian etc.). Is it wrong?

[image: Image of examples of things for applying white fluid to correct text]

Comment: Your dictionary is correct; it's generally called "correction fluid" (or "correction tape", in the case of the solid version, like the lower right of your picture) or "white-out" (which was originally a brand name, "wite-out") in casual speech.

Comment: All of the answers are accurate.  I just wanted to say it bothers me that this is called ***correction fluid*** or (by your friends) ***corrector*** since it doesn't actually *correct* anything.  If anything it should be called ***effacing fluid*** or ***effacer***, since it merely *removes* the error.

Comment: It does not correct text. You use it to white out (cover) typewritten errors in texts and you can retype over it (with an old-fashioned typewriter) or write in a correction by hand. Correction fluid, I have never ever heard. I suspect many of you are quite  young and might have never actually used this on a regular basis. In today's world, you fix the error and just reprint the text. It is only used today in unusual circumstances....[mostly legal].

Comment: @Andrew, If so, it also doesn't really remove the error, it merely **covers** the error but the error is still there.

Comment: It would be nice to know the ages of those responding here. I have to say I have never  heard anyone call this "correction fluid" in an actual work (office) situation. And, today, it has mostly disappeared from use. Corrector is not used in AmE.

Comment: Here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_fluid

Comment: Do you care what people actually say or some technical expression from Wikipedia. That may be the technical term, but it is not used in offices. in 35 years of office work, I only have heard white out (AmE) and tippex (BrE).

Comment: I work in a UK office where some legal documents must be original and unaltered. The instructions say "Do not use correction fluid on this form" but if a submitter has ignored that, our staff universally say "Hey! This one's got Tipp-Ex on it!". You often see 'tippex' for Tipp-Ex in emails about this topic.

Comment: @Andrew True that the term "correction fluid" isn't strictly accurate. But then, lots of names for things are inaccurate or misleading. An "emergency brake" is not normally used in emergencies. The "Democratic Republic of North Korea" is neither democratic nor a republic. Etc.

Comment: @Jay  Oh, I know.  I'm just doing a George Carlin, *"Didja ever wonder why they call it 'correction fluid'?  It doesn't correct anything!  After you use it, you still have to correct the mistake **yourself**, otherwise you have an even bigger mistake!"*

Comment: This is generating quite a lot of discussion, both technical & comedic... for something I haven't even seen in use in the past 25 years, since we all got computers & printers ;-)

Comment: In New Zealand it was called Twink in some areas.

Comment: We used to call it "corflu" when I was active in the zine scene some 40 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

It's **[correction fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_fluid)** or tape.

[Wite Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wite-Out), [Liquid Paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Paper) & [Tipp-Ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipp-Ex) are all brand names, though they tend to be used as generic descriptions too, like Hoover is used for  vacuum cleaners.

Comment: Ironically, *Hoover* is not commonly used generically in the U.S., although it would be understood. *Googling* might be a more universal example.

Comment: Yeah - same happens with sticky tape [sellotape/duck tape] & others. The pond is a real product splitter ;-)

Comment: Sellotape for leftpondians is *scotch tape*, which has been largely genericized; however, 3M clings to the *Scotch* trademark by sticking it in other things like Scotchgard and Scotchlite. A most interesting case is *Bic*, which I have heard used generically for a disposable cigarette lighter, a ballpoint pen, and a disposable razor, and I can only imagine the everyday disasters that might unfold as a result.

Comment: Possibly with slightly less embarrassment factor than the potential for [Durex](https://thedorsetknob.co.uk/5536/sticky-tape-antifreeze-and-condoms/)

Comment: In offices I've worked in, it was always called "white out" in casual conversation, and "correction fluid" in any sort of formal written document. I don't know if the Wite Out people still own a trademark on that, if so, you might hear from their lawyers if you use the term generically. Of course since typewriters went the way of the dodo bird, I don't think I've heard anyone talk about white out, correction fluid, or any equivalent term in many years.

Comment: When I was a kid at school in the UK in the early 1960s we were banned from using a 'Biro' (capital B) for writing assignments or class work. They harmed your handwriting, allegedly.

Answer (score 4):

What things are called is highly dependent on locale. Even within the U.S. there is [considerable variation in terminology](http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/) for everyday items,

In North America, the image you provide depicts bottles of *correction fluid* as well as *correction tape* and a *correction pen*. I have never heard *correcting fluid* or *corrector*, but they could be in use in other parts of the world.

> **[correction fluid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/correction_fluid)** *mass noun* An opaque liquid painted over a typed or written error so as to allow for the insertion of the correct character. [Oxford Living Dictionaries]

*White-out* is also common in North America, likely a [genericization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks) of Wite-Out, which is a BIC brand of correction fluid. By the same token, Tipp-Ex may be used in Europe, though no one on this side of the Atlantic has ever heard of it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its called all those things: "correction fluid" and "white-out" are probably the most common but "corrector" is also reasonable, in context. It is also often called by one of the brand names "Tippex" and "liquid paper" are possible.

I (a Brit) would use "tippex" for the white liquid and "correction tape" for the white tape.

> Remove any correction tape or correction fluid (e.g. tippex) from your pencil case as you cannot take these into an exam. (Birmingham University exam regulations)